# PHP Explode into MYSQL only displaying last value

Tags: php, mysql

My $keywords are `Design~!~Development~!~Print`:

```
$keywordsplit = explode('~!~',$keywords); 

foreach($keywordsplit as $keysplit){

   $sqlkeyword= "INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($keysplit) . "')";

}

$keywordtest = mysql_query( $sqlkeyword, $conn );
```

In my keywords table I'm only getting the word Print. Can someone explain to me why that is?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened is that variable got overwritten. You could do something like this (and suggestion):

```
$raw_keyword = 'Design~!~Development~!~Print';
$keywordsplit = explode('~!~',$raw_keyword);
$values = array();
foreach($keywordsplit as $value) {
    $values[] = "('".$value."')";
}

$sqlkeyword = "INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES ".implode(',', $values);
echo $sqlkeyword; // INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES ('Design'),('Development'),('Print')
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put query inside the loop, otherwise only the last one is executed.

```
foreach($keywordsplit as $keysplit) {
   $sqlkeyword= "INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($keysplit)."')";
　 $keywordtest = mysql_query( $sqlkeyword, $conn );
}
```

And you could also build a sql to insert multiple rows at once.

Comment: The solution you provided puts nothing in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$sqlkeyword` in each iteration, thus only the last "keyword" is stored. You would need to execute the statement inside the loop or write a multi-insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your $sqlkeyword in foreeach will return only last value. because you put your mysql_query outside foreach.
You can use this method to run mysql_query for every foreach keyword

```
$keywords = "Design~!~Development~!~Print";
$keywordsplit = explode('~!~',$keywords); 

foreach($keywordsplit as $keysplit) {
    $sqlkeyword = "INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($keysplit)."')"; 
    $keywordtest = mysql_query( $sqlkeyword, $conn );
}
```

or this method to save the foreach keyword as array

```
$keywords = "Design~!~Development~!~Print";
$keywordsplit = explode('~!~',$keywords); 
$arraykeyword = array();

foreach($keywordsplit as $keysplit) {
    $arraykeyword[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($keysplit)."')";
}
$sqlkeyword = "INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES " . implode( ',', $arraykeyword); 
$keywordtest = mysql_query( $sqlkeyword, $conn );
```

First method look simple but will consume more memory than second method